# Audio Interface sounds distorted and records only mono

Tags: audio-recording, audio-interfaces, macbook-pro

I'm new to audio recording and have been struggling a lot with connecting an audio interface to my macbook pro running macOS Catalina.

I have an M-audio M-track solo. It has two stereo inputs that both can be set to LINE input.
When I connect a LINE out (a drum computer or just my phone playing spotify), the sound from the M-Audio sounds truly awful. It's like many frequencies are missing, and it sounds far away.

When I record it anyway, in Quicktime audio, the sound records in MONO only, making it even worse. Audacity won't record anything at all from the M-Audio.

I've already been looking at support forums of M-Audio and my drum computer. I had this exact same issue with another Audio Interface. Is this a MAC OS issue perhaps? Or am I missing some crucial connection on how to record audio?[image]

Thanks!

Comment: "It has two stereo inputs" - not according to the product page & manual, it has two mono inputs. The photo shows only one input in use - mono. If the drum machine is a stereo out, then you need a splitter. I'd start by reading the manual more carefully - https://m-audio.com/support/documents

Comment: Wow, I've read so many reviews, they all say the interface has stereo-line-in. So they meant you need to use both inputs to get it... I wish that had been made clearer! Why would anyone want to record mono??? I remember my old windows 98 PC had a simple stereo line-in. I'm honestly baffled why I need to buy a complete music production studio just to get a stereo line-in on a macbook.

Comment: _"Why would anyone want to record mono"_ 
Why not? A stereo recording is really nothing more than two mono channels, which when combined gives you a stereo image of the sound. I've yet to encounter a console or audio interface with stereo inputs (other than 2x mono plugs). I mainly do live stuff however, so studio gear might be different from what I'm used to...

Comment: Lead vocal, guitar, bass… all mono instruments. Kick & snare usually, too. Pro & semi-pro gear doesn't use stereo cables/plugs/sockets, it uses mono. If you need stereo, you use two of them. That's just how it's always been.